# Как получить NFA слова в Forth?

Tags: forth

Как получить значения поля NFA слова в SP-Forth? (по мотивам [вопроса](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.forth.spf/2352) из рассылки spf-dev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нету стандартного способа напрямую получить адрес NFA из `xt` или из строки с именем слова.

В 2013 г. комитет [Forth200x](http://www.forth200x.org/) принял [The optional Programming-Tools word set](https://forth-standard.org/standard/tools), в котором закреплен способ получения и использования непрозрачного токена имени `nt`.

Так, слово [`TRAVERSE-WORDLIST`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/tools/TRAVERSE-WORDLIST)`( i*x xt wid -- j*x )` позволяет перебрать `nt` всех слов из заданного списка слов. Слово `NAME>STRING ( nt -- addr count )` дает имя слова из `nt`.

В SP-Forth 4.21 слова работы с `nt` доступны после подключения `lib/include/wordlist-tools.f`

Для отладочных целей в ядре есть слово `WordByAddr ( addr-x -- addr count )`; оно дает имя слова, к телу которого *может* относится указанный адрес `addr-x`.

Answer (score 0):

В SPF есть слово для получения NFA
NEAR_NFA возьмёт xt и вернёт его же и собственно NFA, если оно есть, иначе ноль

Также в папке devel  уже не помню кем было написано определение >NAME

Comment: Слово `NEAR_NFA` объявлено устаревшим и оставлено только для обратной совместимости. Кроме того, оно вернет заведомо неверный результат, если `xt` принадлежит анонимному определению (например, если слово определенно через `:NONAME`). Определения `>NAME` в devel — тоже ненадежные хаки.

Comment: С этим не поспоришь :)